# function inside flow is not getting called during retrofit api call

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

During api the code inside the 'flow{}' is not getting called, below is the order of my execution.
Execution starts from view model

```
private fun getAppConfig() = viewModelScope.launch {
        _appConfigFlow.update {
            AppConfigState.Loading
        }
        val response = getAppConfigUseCase.invoke()
    }
```

below is the usecase

```
class GetAppConfigUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: AppConfigRepository
) {
    suspend operator fun invoke() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.getAppConfig()
    }
}
```

below is the repository

```
interface AppConfigRepository {
    suspend fun getAppConfig(): Flow<Result<AppConfig>?>
}
```

below is the repository implementation

```
@Singleton
class AppConfigRepositoryImp @Inject constructor(
    private val remoteDataSource: AppConfigRemoteDataSource
) : AppConfigRepository {

    override suspend fun getAppConfig(): Flow<Result<AppConfig>?> = flow {
        remoteDataSource.getAppConfigData()
    }
}
```

below is the remote data source

```
interface AppConfigRemoteDataSource {
    suspend fun getAppConfigData(): Flow<Result<AppConfig>?>
}
```

below is the remote data source implementation

```
class AppConfigRemoteDataSourceImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val apiService: ApiService
) : AppConfigRemoteDataSource {
    override suspend fun getAppConfigData(): Flow<Result<AppConfig>?> = toResultFlow {
        apiService.getAppConfig()
    }

    private fun <T> toResultFlow(call: suspend () -> Response<T>?): Flow<Result<T>?> {
        return flow {
            emit(Result.Loading)
        }
    }
}
```

I added a debugger in the above functions and I can see that every function is getting called except `apiService.getAppConfig()`. It is not getting called so I am not getting any result. But if I am using the normal `Response<T>` from retrofit I am getting the response but not when using the flow. Please help me to find the solution
this is api service

```
@GET(".")
    suspend fun getAppConfig(): Response<AppConfig>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AppConfigRemoteDataSourceImpl.toResultFlow()`, you only return a Flow that emits a Loading state and nothing else. It ignores the lambda parameter you passed to it.

You probably meant to do:

```
    private fun <T> toResultFlow(call: suspend () -> Response<T>?): Flow<Result<T>?> {
        return flow {
            emit(Result.Loading)
            emit(call())
        }
    }
```

I suggest using `Flow<Result<T>>` instead of `Flow<Result<T>?>`. There's no case where your Flow would ever emit null, so why make it difficult to use in the collector?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was checking the debugger inside function, totally forgot about result flow.